# How does an android factory reset work?

Tags: factory-reset, 4.3-jelly-bean

When performing a factory reset, does Android remove all the added applications and user data or does it completely reflash an image of the OS

I am running on jelly bean 4.3 stock

Answer (score 2):

When performing a factory reset:

- /system is untouched since it's normally read-only anyway
- /data is formatted
- /cache is formatted
- /sdcard is not touched unless you specify. Note that apps on the sdcard will still be erased.

So, to answer your question, the system is **not** reflash end, but instead the data and cache partitions are formatted.

Comment: If you have an emulated sd card, will it be touched?

Comment: Depends on where it stores data. If its on the phone, then yes, it will. Normally I would suggest making Titanium or Nandroid Backups, but it seems like you don't have one :).